# graph dependency with some equation over arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, arrows, graphs

I want to reproduce the figure below with TIKZ. The node `t_i` depends on its neighboring nodes, so that the further away one is in the temporal axis, the weaker the dependence becomes.

[image]

As you can see in the figure below, I have reproduced the structure of the graph but I do not know how to make the equations over the arrows.

[image]

```
   \documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata,calc}
   \tikzset{
   main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, draw =black!80, node 
   distance = 10mm},
    box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}
   }
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   % put nodes
   \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1)   {$t_i$};
   \node[main] (t2) [right= of t1] {$t_{i+1}$};
   \node[main] (t3) [right= of t2] {$t_{i+2}$};
   \node[main] (tn) [right= of t3] {$t_{n}$};
   \node[main] (t)  [left=  of t1] {$t_{i-1}$};
   \node[main] (tt) [left=  of t]  {$t_{i-2}$};
   \node[main] (t0) [left=  of tt] {$t_{0}$};

   % make path ...
   \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
   \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

   % draw arrows
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=45,in=135] (tn) node [midway,below]{$P(k=0|\lambda=i)$}; 
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=35,in=135] (t3);
   \draw [->] (t1) to (t2);
   \draw [->] (t1) to (t);
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=135,in=35] (tt);
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=135,in=35] (t0);
   \end{tikzpicture} 
   \end{document}
```

So, if you have suggestions to make this graphic even more beautiful (structure), please do not hesitate.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**
 I modified the code as  @Ignasi suggested and I get this:

[image]
Is there a simple way to prevent equations from crossing arrows as shown in the figure for arrow t_i to t_ {i + 1}?

```
     \draw [->] (t1) to [out=45,in=135] node [rotate=-5,above]{\tiny 
      $P(k=n\mid\lambda=1)$} (tn);
     \draw [->] (t1) to [out=35,in=135] node [rotate=-5,above]{\tiny 
      $P(k=i+1\mid\lambda=1)$}(t3) ;
```

**EDIT 2**
As suggested by @Ignasi, i get the following picture. However, how could I add an equation between the `t_i`and  `t_ {i + 1}` ( `t_i` and `t_{i-1}`)? 
[image]

Below the modified code :

```
           \documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
           \usepackage{tikz}
           \usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata,calc}
           \tikzset{
            main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, draw                =black!80, node distance = 10mm},
            box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}
           }
           \begin{document}
           \begin{tikzpicture}
              % put nodes
              \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1)   {$t_i$};
              \node[main] (t2) [right= of t1] {$t_{i+1}$};
              \node[main] (t3) [right= of t2] {$t_{i+2}$};
              \node[main] (tn) [right= of t3] {$t_{n}$};
              \node[main] (t)  [left=  of t1] {$t_{i-1}$};
              \node[main] (tt) [left=  of t]  {$t_{i-2}$};
              \node[main] (t0) [left=  of tt] {$t_{0}$};

              % make path ...
              \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
              \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

              % draw arrows
              \draw [->] (t1) to [out=45,in=135] node [midway, above]               {$P(k=n|\lambda=i)$} (tn); 
              \draw [->] (t1) to [out=-45,in=-135] node [midway, below]               {$P(k=i+2|\lambda=i)$}(t3);
              \draw [->] (t1) to node[midway, below] {$P(k=i+1|\lambda=i)$}               (t2);
              \draw [->] (t1) to node[midway, above] {$P(k=i-1|\lambda=i)$}(t);
              \draw [->] (t1) to [out=-135,in=-45] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i-2|\lambda=i)$}(tt);
              \draw [->] (t1) to [out=135,in=35] node [midway, above]{$P(k=0|\lambda=i)$}(t0);
           \end{tikzpicture} 
           \end{document}
```

Comment: Put the node before the end of the path: `\draw [->] (t1) to [out=45,in=135] node [midway,below]{$P(k=0|\lambda=i)$} (tn);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to distribute links to avoid overlapping equations.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata,calc}
\tikzset{
   main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, 
        draw =black!80, node distance = 10mm},
   box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   % put nodes
   \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1)   {$t_i$};
   \node[main] (t2) [right= of t1] {$t_{i+1}$};
   \node[main] (t3) [right= of t2] {$t_{i+2}$};
   \node[main] (tn) [right= of t3] {$t_{n}$};
   \node[main] (t)  [left=  of t1] {$t_{i-1}$};
   \node[main] (tt) [left=  of t]  {$t_{i-2}$};
   \node[main] (t0) [left=  of tt] {$t_{0}$};

   % make path ...
   \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
   \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

   % draw arrows
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=45,in=135] node [midway, above]{$P(k=n|\lambda=i)$} (tn); 
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=-45,in=-135] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i+2|\lambda=i)$}(t3);
   \draw [->] (t1) to (t2);
   \draw [->] (t1) to (t);
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=-135,in=-45] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i-2|\lambda=i)$}(tt);
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=135,in=35] node [midway, above]{$P(k=0|\lambda=i)$}(t0);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Answer to EDIT 2:**

Increase distance between `t` and side states:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata,calc}
\tikzset{
   main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, 
        draw =black!80, node distance = 10mm},
   box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   % put nodes
   \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1)   {$t_i$};
   \node[main] (t2) [right= 3cm of t1] {$t_{i+1}$};
   \node[main] (t3) [right= of t2] {$t_{i+2}$};
   \node[main] (tn) [right= of t3] {$t_{n}$};
   \node[main] (t)  [left= 3cm of t1] {$t_{i-1}$};
   \node[main] (tt) [left=  of t]  {$t_{i-2}$};
   \node[main] (t0) [left=  of tt] {$t_{0}$};

   % make path ...
   \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
   \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

   % draw arrows
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=45,in=135] node [midway, above]{$P(k=n|\lambda=i)$} (tn); 
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=-45,in=-135] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i+2|\lambda=i)$}(t3);
   \draw [->] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i+1|\lambda=i)$}(t2);
   \draw [->] (t1) to  node [midway, above] {$P(k=i-1|\lambda=i)$} (t);
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=-135,in=-45] node [midway, below]{$P(k=i-2|\lambda=i)$}(tt);
   \draw [->] (t1) to [out=135,in=35] node [midway, above]{$P(k=0|\lambda=i)$}(t0);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in fact the structure of your graph is beautiful. Please look at my second EDIT about putting equation between  `t_i` and `t_{i+1}` or `t_{i-1}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata,calc}
\tikzset{
  main/.style={circle, minimum size = 10mm, thick, draw =black!80, node 
    distance = 10mm},
  box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % put nodes
  \node[main,draw =red!80] (t1)   {$t_i$};
  \node[main] (t2) [right= of t1] {$t_{i+1}$};
  \node[main] (t3) [right= of t2] {$t_{i+2}$};
  \node[main] (tn) [right= of t3] {$t_{n}$};
  \node[main] (t)  [left=  of t1] {$t_{i-1}$};
  \node[main] (tt) [left=  of t]  {$t_{i-2}$};
  \node[main] (t0) [left=  of tt] {$t_{0}$};

  % make path ...
  \path (t3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (tn);
  \path (tt) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (t0);

  % draw arrows
  \draw [->] (t1) to [out=75,in=135]  node [midway,above]{$P(k=n|\lambda=i)$} (tn); 
  \draw [->] (t1) to [out=35,in=135] node [midway,above]{$P(k=i + 2|\lambda=i)$}  (t3);
  \draw [->] (t1) to (t2);
  \draw [->] (t1) to (t);
  \draw [->] (t1) to [out=145,in=45] node [midway,above]{$P(k= i- 2|\lambda=i)$} (tt);
  \draw [->] (t1) to [out=105,in=45] node [midway,above]{$P(k=0|\lambda=i)$}  (t0);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]